# Wso2 policy tier update from gold to silver

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We wso2 4.1

1. We have 10 APIs in publisher with 4 tier subscription free , gold, silver, unlimited.
2. We have multiple user initially with free tier if they want to go for any paid tier like gold or unlimited
3. We are create access role as access_gold, access_unlimited like in carbon and added in throttle policy at admin portal as permission group.

4 user who want to access api A with thottle subscription gold we are added in gold access so need  role but it allows all other api with gold access

How to resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your question is not quite clear. How the permissions of a subscription policy works is, if the allowed roles are given for the gold tier, then only the users with access_gold role will be able to use it in developer portal.
So if gold tier is attached to both API A and B in publisher portal, then both API A and B are allowed to subscribe from gold tier by a user with access_gold role. If you want to only allow access to API A, then you need to create another subscription policy specific to API A, like gold_API_A tier and only use that for API A from publisher portal.